# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

I just updated sdk, google play services and google repository, but still this error happened. Please help, I want to integrate authentication using phone number.

[SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pspgG.png)

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNzwq.png)

Build.gradle Module:Project

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/module
return
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.gradle Module:App

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.*****"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please post bot your app level and project level gradle files

Comment: post your  firebase dependencies added to gradle

Comment: Post your *build.gradle* file.

Comment: @LucaRossi, Now check my edited post please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Firebase documentation it says:

> Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
>      the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager

Updating Google Repository should help with `Failed to resolve` issues as well (at the time of writing these lines, Google Repository version is 57).

So solving this should be rather simple. Here are the steps you should take:

1. Open SDK Manager.
2. Select SDK Tools on the top tabs.
3. Scroll down, under Support Repository select Google Repository.
4. Hit the OK button.
5. As soon as installation is completed, change the Firebase dependencies version to 11.0.2.
6. Click on the "Sync Now" button.
7. Enjoy Firebase =)

Comment: There's no `Support Repository select Google Repository.`

Comment: Hi @West, I just checked and it seems that it was removed by Google for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to include the google play services plugin add these lines of code

App level gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2"
    ...

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  <-- this line ath the bottom of it
```

Project level gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'  <--- This Line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager

Answer (score 0):

Google have shifted their new repositories from jcenter to maven google.

Add

```
google()
```

inside repositories in project build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Add Googles own maven repository to your build-gradle file:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
        }
    }
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me setting play-services and firebase equal versions, like this:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0"

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using older version of Auth.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

Comment: old version does not contains phone number authentication.